# Can I select a specific date range from mysql when the field is a varchar

Tags: mysql

I want to use the following code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Schedule 
WHERE SCH_AgentID = "&AgentDB("AGT_ID")&" 
AND STR_TO_DATE(SCH_SubmitDate, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND CURDATE()"
```

Or similar, I have tried a number of variations which I suspect should work fine but return no results and no errors. If i drop the 6 month end of the statement it correctly returns all of the results.

The only thing which I think might cause the problem is the SCH_SubmitDate is a varchar field due to issues getting mysql to store process and return dates in UK format.

Anyone know if this could be the issue and is there a work around?

Comment: hmm could you provide some data as well if possible on http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual SQL data it is hard to see where the problem would be in this query. However it appears your basic problem is that you expect to take just any string date and store it in the database.

It is not the problem of MySQL if you try to store a date in a format it does not know. You should always convert any date you get to a format that MYSQL can understand, i.e. `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Not doing so will only get you in trouble later on like it does here.

My advise is to create a new column with the `DATE` type to store the dates in and then try to fill those dates using `STR_TO_DATE`. Most probably not every date will convert correctly and those will be your problem.

Comment: "Not doing so will only get you in trouble later on like it does here"
this means a lot while you are working in a big application..